# Can't open resources from jar when launching with double click

Tags: java, resources, jar, double-click

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608286/runnable-jar-runs-fine-with-java-jar-but-problems-with-double-click) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768122/cant-run-a-jar-file-from-the-double-click) but those solutions won't work for me at all.

My jar works perfect with java -jar on command prompt but when it comes to double click, a JFrame window is opened but it fails on these:

```
Scanner fileLat = new Scanner( a.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/motor/resources/lat.txt") );
Scanner fileLong = new Scanner( a.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/motor/resources/long.txt") );
```

Which result on null pointer exceptions and resources not being found.

My directory structure (inside the jar) looks like this:

```
/ (root)
|- META-INF
|- motor
 |- main
  |- Main.class
 |- resources
  |- lat.txt
  |- long.txt
```

And my MANIFEST.MF reads as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: motor.main.Main
```

Edit:
I just attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073250/eclipse-export-to-jar-and-include-resource-files-ant) (especifically, the jar:file:MyJar.jar!/etc...) and it didn't work either.

Comment: what is your current directory? `Class-Path: .` looks suspicious.

Comment: Double-clicking a file on Windows stablishes it to that file's directory, doesn't it? I think so. For the command prompt is a different one but it works.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure. try to output the current directory to console or some file at the program start.

Comment: Tried:
`File test = new File(".");`
`System.out.println(test.getAbsolutePath());`
It returns the directory where the jar is placed.

Comment: that's bad, it means that the problem is somewhere else :(

Comment: For what I've seen, looks like it has to do with using or not -jar option. When I use command prompt I use it with -jar but on double-clicking it just launches normally. I don't quite understand the difference and of course I can't find a solution. : (

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to remove `Class-Path` from the manifest ? 
Defining the classpath is uncommon in the examples I have here : many applications (incl. jEdit and jExt installer) will run without it.

You could also try to add an empty one.

Comment: Not defining the Class-Path game me an error, leaving it blank gave me a different one.

"Invalid or corrupt jarfile" when blank.
"Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from C:\Users\Nirei\Downloads\EarthClock.jar" when no Class-Path attrib.